# Cannot define/undefine preprocessor symbols after the first token in a file

Tags: c#

How can I use #define in C#?

I have this code on C++:

```
#define _DSC_CHANNEL_ERRORS_HPP_

#define DSC_ChannelErrors(value)    (DSC_E01_##value)
```

This can be variable. How I can use it?

All code is on [code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZcLQ9hiN4UU7vof5BlJI2L01kCJw9Umf/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: That's not possible in C#. C# only supports a limited set of preprocessor directives, and macros are generally disallowed. Also, the definitions must be at the beginning of the file, in the project file or on the command line.

Comment: Even in C++ isn't the recommendation these days to avoid macros?

Comment: What do you mean by *"is on code"*? Can you elaborate? The [Google Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Drive) link also seems to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

C# does not support preprocessor symbols like C++.
You have to define them like this:

```
public const int NUM = 1;
```

If you want to create a macro your best option is something like this:

```
public static readonly Func<T> Macro() {};
```

Comment: That's not fully true. C# allows #if instructions for conditiional compilations.

Comment: @PMF Which is why I said it does not support it like C++. I did not say it does not support them at all.

Comment: so it can't possible, that sad

Comment: @jhonestrada You need to think a bit differently to get this to work. But to help you further, please edit your question and include more details about the C++ code you want to port.

Comment: I up the file on https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZcLQ9hiN4UU7vof5BlJI2L01kCJw9Umf/view?usp=sharing you can check it

Comment: @jhonestrada If I'm not mistaking the only reason for your preprocessor symbols and macro are to prevent the C++ name mangling when some legacy C code is using the enum. Since you want to implement that in C# there is no need for all of that as you are not effected by the name mangling which you solve with your preprocessor directive. You are working with C# and C# only. There isn't a compatibility issue you need to resolve.